# How to change the color of a button inside a StreamLit iframe with CSS

Tags: css, iframe, css-selectors, antd, streamlit

I am building a StreamLit app with a [streamlit-text-label](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-text-label/) component (which is a front end for [label studio](https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio), which uses AntD buttons).

For accessibility reasons I need to change the color of the blue update button.

After searching StreamLit Community Forum and Stackoverflow, I have created the following example code: a standard StreamLit button is changed to green to prove the `markdown CSS style injection` works, plus some of my non-working attempts to change the button color.

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_text_label import label_select

st.markdown(
    """
    <style>
        div.stButton > button {background-color: green;}

        div.Controls_container__LTeAA > button {background: purple !important;}
        
        iframe[title="streamlit_text_label.label_select"] .ant-btn {background: orange !important;}
        iframe[title="streamlit_text_label.label_select"] .ant-btn-primary {background: orange !important;}

        .ant-btn {background: violet !important;}
        .ant-btn-primary {background: violet !important;}

        button.ant-btn {background: violet !important;}
        button.ant-btn-primary {background: violet !important;}

    </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True
)

selections = label_select(body="lorem ipsum", labels=["Noun", "Verb"])
st.button("test")
```

Screenshot of the StreamLit app running the above code:

[image: Screenshot of StreamLit app running the above code, note the green button works, but the update button remains stock blue]

Chrome element inspection. I added yellow and purple dots to highlight relevant sections:

[image: Screenshot from Chrome element inspection]

I hypothesis the error is in addressing the element inside the `iframe`, but this example is all local so I don't suspect cross-site scripting problems. After more research, maybe it is cross site security policy, even thought this is running locally.

I cut and pasted the inner iframe button code outside the iframe and the pasted version changed color. Fingers cross that the problem is still how to reference an object in an iframe properly.